# Status:500 error while using POST function in R

Tags: r, post, httr

I am using POST function from httr package using the following command :

```
POST("http://internal-Production-ALB-Loopback-1537714473.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com:5000/api/sendemail/sendAlertEMail/rroy@machinesense.com/sboral@machinesense.com/Ruman"
      , body = "{'msg':'hi'}"
      , encode = "json"
      , verbose() )
```

where 
"rroy@machinesense.com" is to email, sboral@machinesense.com is cc email and "Ruman" is subject of email and I am sending email from server

but using the above command I am getting the following error:

[image]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the URL your own endpoint? Does it require authentication?

Comment: It is a server to server call. It will not open without internal server.

Comment: Pretty hard to help then - the error may well be on your server. You haven't specified  what input it expects.

Comment: If I use postman and use this api, then it is functioning as expected. Only when I call from R, I get this error.

Comment: Are you relying on IAM to authenticate with the API? Otherwise, you probably need credentials.